# nsinstall: Bad file number error on Vista

Tags: uac, windows-vista

I'm attempting to build Firefox on my Windows Vista Ultimate machine. I keep getting the following error:

> nsinstall: Bad file number

I've read that this error is caused because of UAC in Vista. Here are the two articles that lead me to this conclusion. https://wiki.mozilla.org/Penelope_Developer_Page#Windows_Vista and http://www.kevinbrosnan.net/mozilla-build-error-nsinstall-bad-file-number

Using the standard "Run as Administrator", I've attempted to redo my build but I get the exact same error. I also started a normal command prompt as admin and then went to the batch file in mozilla-build (start-msvc8.bat) and ran it. Still, same error at the same point.

Any other insights on how I might either get around this error or perhaps something else is causing the error?

**Note**: I also [posted something here](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.builds/browse_frm/thread/d43e2390f14fad42#) in the hopes to get topic-specific help but I've not heard a peep... After I posted that I found the info on `nsinstall`. Anyway, I prefer SO so I thought I'd try here...

**Update**: I've attempted to completly disable UAC to correct the problem as is suggested by cnemelkasr. I've received the exact same error. This new knowledge is making me think that a file or folder is missing... Does anyone who has experience with NSInstall know what the given error -- Bad file number -- might mean? I figure it might be referring to a file handle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I'm posting the answer here to share the answer with others and to close this question.

After disabling the UAC, it was suggested that the directory depth was interfering with NSInstall. I moved the folder from `c:/Users/Frank/Documents/hg-repos/firefox-src-hgRepo/mozilla-fv-expirement/` to `C:/mozilla-fv-expirement/`. Cleaned all previous build attempts and finally redid my build (with UAC off) and I received a working debug binary.

The suggestion was posted at: [mozilla.dev.builds](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.builds/browse_frm/thread/d43e2390f14fad42#)

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a UAC error, you can try turning off UAC altogether.  I've had to do this for several packages.   There are numerous places on the web to get the instructions for doing that.

http://www.petri.co.il/disable_uac_in_windows_vista.htm is one of them.

Comment: So, as you can see from my update above, I tried this but it didn't help. If you have other suggestions, I'm open to them...

Answer (score 0):

The *"Bad file number"* message in the cases I have seen, is caused by too many arguments passed to `execvp (command, argv)` (or similar) function. But only from *some* programs. An old *bash*, *sh* or a Borland/Watcom program in your **PATH** is an likely candidate.

So when you shorten the name of the build directory, the total size of the command line (that eventually gets passed to `CreateProcess()`) gets shorter. I don't think UAC has anything to do with this since I've seen this on Win-XP too. But it's a bit strange Mozilla would not use relative paths while building. I guess it uses some directory *prefix* value in it's makefiles (I've never tried building it).

If you look at the documentation for `_execvp()`:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xw6zy53.aspx

**E2BIG** is one of the possible `errno` values: 
*The space required for the arguments and environment settings exceeds 32 KB.*

Now, here is the strange part.

*Fact 1*:
On Visual-C/MingW (any version), `strerror(EBADF)` doesn't return *"Bad file number"* .
(it return *"Bad file descriptor*").

*Fact 2*:
On Borland's CBuilder 5.6 and Watcom 1.9 (these do *not* use the MSVC runtime),  `strerror(EBADF)` does indeed return *"Bad file number"*.

*Theory*:
Is possible that Borland, Watcom (and other CRTs too?) mixes up the meaning of `E2BIG` and `EBADF`. Did that make any sense? Someone please correct me if you have a better theory. 
I'm a bit confused myself...

*Conclusion*:
 Either shorten the size of your environment (easiest) or shorten the command-line (not always easy).

--gv